# CSS Flex, last two items aren't the same width as the rest

Tags: css, flexbox

I've got a container with items that are set to flex:1 0 25%; which take up roughly one third each, so I have rows of 3. When it comes to the last row where there are only two items, they go 50% width each, why is that?

```
.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.item {
    flex: 1 0 25%;
}
```

Comment: Please add a code snippet of what you have done.

Comment: please provide more code - html and css - you can paste it  in the question or use codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: because you gave them flex: 1 0 25%; The 1 is for flex--grow: 1; so your items grow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, the behavior you described is because you set the **flex** property of your flex items to:

```
flex: 1 0 25%;
```

which is short for:

```
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: 25%;
```

This means, that all of your flex-items have a width basis of 25% of the flex-container, while they cannot be smaller (no-shrink) and instead take all of the remaining space because of **flex-grow: 1;**

And because of that your flex-items will behave as follows:

1 flex-item will take 100% of the flex-containers width,

2 flex-items will each take 50% of the flex-containers width,

3 flex-items will each take 33.3333% of the flex-containers witdh and so on.

This also happens to apply for **each row** when you have **flex-wrap: wrap;**

If you want each row to have 3 items with a width of roughly 1/3, I suggest you try to set the flex property of your flex items to:

```
flex: 0 0 33.3333%
```

**CodePen:** https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jeXMBK?editors=1100#0

Alternatively you could use **CSS-Grid** which is the better choice most of the time, if you are dealing with 2-dimensional layouts.

**Edit:** Added CodePen sample